# How to change SharePoint search page URL?

Tags: search, publishing-site

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I am using publishing portal template.

By default, the search page is using results.aspx as the search result page. I want to change results.aspx to another page (my custom search page to show results, e.g. customsearchresults.aspx), how do I change it?

Answer (score 1):

I think i already tried to answered that question at the end of your other recent questions [Permission issue when editing a page using SharePoint Designer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/943/permission-issue-when-editing-a-page-using-sharepoint-designer/949#949)

Comment: I read it, and it is about how to customize search result. But what I want to do is to change search page URL.

Comment: well the last link describes half of the process (creating a custom search page and tab...).
This article in SharePoint magazine also describes the process:  http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/development/customizing-search-series-created-the-custom-results-page

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Edit the page
2. Find the web part that contains where to enter the search term, which should be called something like "Search Box"
3. Modify the settings on that web part and look for something like "Target search results page URL"
4. Change the value from `results.aspx` to your custom results page
5. Click OK and save, etc...